# How do you create a cbuffer or global variable that is gpu modifiable?

Tags: shaders, directx11, hlsl

I'm implementing [tonemapping](http://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2010/04/30/a-closer-look-at-tone-mapping/) in a pixel shader, for hdr lighting.

The vertex shader outputs vertices with colors.  I need to find the max color and save it in a global.

However when I try and write the global in my hlsl code,

```
//clamp the max color below by this color
clamp( maxColor, output.color, float4( 1e6,1e6,1e6,1e6 ) ) ;
```

I see:

> error X3025: global variables are implicitly constant, enable compatibility mode to allow modification

What is the correct way to declare a shader global in d3d11 that the vertex shader can write to, and the pixel shader can read?

I realize this is a bit tough since the vertex shaders are supposed to run in parallel, and introducing a shader global that they all write to means a lock..

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with 11.0.